# How can anomalies (insertion,deletion and updation) be introduced into Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle

I was trying to learn Normalization in Oracle database, but struck in understanding the problem for which normalization is the solution i.e. I am unable to understand different anomalies (insertion,deletion and updation) properly. Not that, I do not know anything about them; I learned the theory from my text book (Navathe & Elmsari). Anomaly is the problem raised in a database during these processes and result in inconsistent database. But I can not properly visualize it i.e. how can anomalies get introduced in the database. So, it will be very helpful if somebody comes up with a really simple database example and help me understand how can these anomalies be introduced in the database. I tried to find in the internet, but could not find good examples.

Answer (score 6):

**Anamoly**: difficult to classify

[image]

The Problems resulting from data redundancy in an un-normalized database table are collectively known as update anomalies. So any database insertion, deletion or modification that leaves the database in an inconsistent state is said to have caused an update anomaly. They are classified as

**Insertion anomalies:**  To insert the details of a new member of staff located at branch B1 into the Tbl_Staff_Branch Table shown above, we must enter the correct details of branch numner B1 so that the branch details are consistent with the values for branch B1 in other rows.
To insert the details of a new branch that currently has no members of staff into the Tbl_Staff_Branch table, it is necessory to enter nulls for the staff details which is not allowed as staffID is the primary key.  But if you normalize Tbl_Staff_Branch,  which is in Second Normal Form (2NF) to Third Normal Dorm (3NF), you end up with Tbl_Staff and Tbl_Branch and you shouldn't have the problems mentioned above.

**Deletion anomalies:**  If we delete a row from the Tbl_Staff_Branch table that represents the last member of staff located at that branch, (for e.g. row with Branch numbers B",B3 or B4) the detals about that branch are also lost from the Database.

**Modification anomalies:**   Should we need to change the address of a particular branch in the Tbl_Staff_Branch table, we must update the rows of all staff located at that branch. If this modification is not carried out on all the relevant rows, the database will become inconsistent.

Read more: http://www.mahipalreddy.com/dbdesign/dbqa.htm#update